A question on kNN imputation
I would like to build a machine learning model given a (tabular) dataset. A way to deal with missing values which are assumed to be missing at random is the kNN algorithm. My question pertains to the choice of k. If we are using kNN for a classification problem, we can just leave out a test set and see which value of k leads to the highest accuracy. For imputation, one way to choose k would be to treat the variable with missing values as the dependent variable, which we call var for convenience, and use those rows whose values of var we know for training and testing. Another way would be to generate different complete datasets using different k, and choose the k which gives me the best performance for my model. Which of these two ways is better, and why?
